# Jquery + CORS+ Basic Auth with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, jersey, cors, basic-authentication

I'm having trouble to make a simple GET request with Basic Auth to one of my CORS enabled web server with jQuery.

**The problem seems to be linked to Basic Auth since when I deactivate it on my server, the request works correctly**. However, with Basic Auth enabled, it fails with `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401`

**I added the OPTIONS method to return a response with 4 headers**:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, 
`Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS`, 
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true`.

and added the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to all responses.

**I also tried to make the OPTIONS request with Postman and I can see the CORS headers:**

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials → true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *`

I also tried to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:80` instead of `*` but the result was the same.

my javascript code is the following:

```
$.ajax({
url: this.host,
type: "GET",
data: {
    something: "something"
},
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + this.credentials,
    "Accept": "application/json"
},
cache: false
}).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
}).fail(function (xhr, textStatus) {
})
```

My server is a simple java webapp with Jersey running on Tomcat7.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the headers in `beforeSend`:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
  url: this.host,
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    something: "something"
  },
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + that.credentials);
  },
  cache: false
}).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
}).fail(function (xhr, textStatus) {
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve the issue, I still get the same error message :(

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is your problem.  You can't use wildcards in this header when doing authenticated requests.  Instead, explicitly set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the value from the request's Origin header.